# What Azure service can I use to subscribe and listen to a web socket feed?

Tags: azure

I need to subscribe to a third-party web socket feed and process the messages received (e.g. write them to a queue).

I'm testing the service locally with a C# Windows Console application and it works just fine: I subscribe to the feed, I add even handlers, and then I do `Console.ReadLine()` in order to keep the application running and listening to the feed.

Now I need to deploy it to `Azure`. So my question is - what `Azure` service is appropriate for this scenario? That is, I need to deploy, subscribe to the feed and keep it running.

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Cloud Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cloud-services/) is what you're looking for.  This is (as of right now at least) their official always on service for your use case.  It is a **managed windows service**, meaning that it will manage making sure that your service is running and bringing it up and down.  You can set auto-scaling if you need it.

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/)

Comment: Thanks, I found continuous web jobs to solve my needs, as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs#CreateContinuous

Comment: Keep in mind: Cloud Services are Windows-only stateless VMs. And they have several other limitations, even compared to Windows-based VMs. And they have a different deployment model as well, and require Visual Studio on Windows (or Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to deploy a Windows service to a virtual machine, but that could be an overkill.
The other alternative is [continuous web jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs#CreateContinuous).